# windows 7 diskpart command undo selecting a disk

Tags: windows-7, partitioning

ok I got curious (and cocky) about looking at partitions - I did a diskpart
which then I did a rescan, then a list disks which gave me DISK 0, DISK 1 AND DISK 2. I then did a select disk 0 and it told me Disk 0 is now the selected disk and it put an asterisk next to the Disk 0 - what did I do and how to I get rid of this asterisk. HELP!!!!

Comment: No changes have been made. The selection is for the purpose of performing further operations on the selected disk. If you exist DiskPart, nothing will happen to the data on the disk.

Answer (score 1):

The asterisk is simply a method that marks the disk you have selected, and indicates which disk actions will be performed on if you choose to do so.

This asterisk is equivalent to the highlighting of a line in Windows Explorer. For example, when you single click on a file, the line turns blue. You haven't opened the file or changed anything, it's simply showing that is the file you have selected.